# Day of the week vs time on BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I am completely stuck on how to approach this problem: I'm basically trying to figure out when is the best time to tweet on twitter, based on a list of timestamps:

Here are the raw values:

```
{2012-02-15 11:58:38 -0500,2012-02-14 20:18:03 -0500,2012-02-14 15:59:18 -0500,2012-02-14 15:46:30 -0500,2012-02-14 15:44:11 -0500,2012-02-14 15:34:23 -0500,2012-02-14 13:14:45 -0500,2012-02-14 12:09:18 -0500,2012-02-14 11:44:13 -0500,2012-02-13 21:30:05 -0500,2012-02-13 17:12:31 -0500,2012-02-13 17:12:11 -0500,2012-02-13 13:03:09 -0500,2012-02-12 23:34:37 -0500,2012-02-12 23:30:04 -0500,2012-02-12 23:22:53 -0500,2012-02-12 12:56:40 -0500,2012-02-11 14:52:10 -0500,2012-02-10 20:08:30 -0500,2012-02-10 16:24:57 -0500,2012-02-09 16:34:40 -0500,2012-02-09 12:41:37 -0500,2012-02-09 12:41:04 -0500,2012-02-09 11:07:45 -0500,2012-02-09 11:06:29 -0500,2012-02-09 09:53:11 -0500,2012-02-09 09:51:12 -0500,2012-02-09 07:31:04 -0500,2012-02-08 20:38:18 -0500,2012-02-08 19:39:10 -0500,2012-02-08 19:16:42 -0500,2012-02-08 18:54:37 -0500,2012-02-08 18:00:31 -0500,2012-02-07 20:25:14 -0500,2012-02-07 17:36:19 -0500,2012-02-07 16:54:37 -0500,2012-02-07 14:32:31 -0500,2012-02-07 13:53:10 -0500,2012-02-07 13:31:14 -0500,2012-02-07 12:22:51 -0500,2012-02-07 12:21:57 -0500,2012-02-07 11:12:31 -0500,2012-02-06 17:56:32 -0500,2012-02-05 20:29:34 -0500,2012-02-05 10:05:09 -0500,2012-02-04 17:05:16 -0500,2012-02-03 19:34:13 -0500,2012-02-03 15:36:14 -0500,2012-02-03 14:21:04 -0500,2012-02-03 12:25:53 -0500,2012-02-03 00:44:51 -0500,2012-02-03 00:37:29 -0500,2012-02-02 16:39:31 -0500,2012-02-02 16:38:39 -0500,2012-01-29 13:23:25 -0500,2012-01-28 18:55:28 -0500,2012-01-26 13:13:43 -0500,2012-01-26 11:42:41 -0500,2012-01-26 08:58:36 -0500,2012-01-26 07:42:36 -0500,2012-01-25 22:51:27 -0500,2012-01-25 22:51:27 -0500,2012-01-25 20:43:29 -0500,2012-01-25 20:12:00 -0500,2012-01-25 20:11:28 -0500,2012-01-25 20:11:28 -0500,2012-01-25 18:47:40 -0500,2012-01-25 17:01:58 -0500,2012-01-25 17:01:18 -0500,2012-01-25 15:27:57 -0500,2012-01-25 13:00:05 -0500,2012-01-25 12:54:50 -0500,2012-01-25 12:33:31 -0500,2012-01-25 11:08:38 -0500,2012-01-25 00:29:32 -0500,2012-01-24 20:17:27 -0500,2012-01-24 16:23:31 -0500,2012-01-24 16:23:31 -0500,2012-01-24 12:12:50 -0500,2012-01-24 11:19:45 -0500,2012-01-23 21:00:46 -0500,2012-01-23 18:52:58 -0500,2012-01-22 20:28:58 -0500,2012-01-22 16:33:37 -0500,2012-01-21 22:03:11 -0500,2012-01-21 16:08:24 -0500,2012-01-20 21:34:39 -0500,2012-01-20 10:25:51 -0500,2012-01-19 21:03:46 -0500,2012-01-19 21:03:46 -0500,2012-01-18 23:44:54 -0500,2012-01-18 19:56:17 -0500,2012-01-18 19:55:32 -0500,2012-01-18 13:05:58 -0500,2012-01-17 19:58:55 -0500,2012-01-17 19:55:15 -0500,2012-01-17 19:02:29 -0500,2012-01-17 18:53:18 -0500,2012-01-14 18:43:48 -0500,2012-01-13 10:26:19 -0500,2012-01-12 13:40:40 -0500,2012-01-09 17:37:17 -0500,2012-01-07 16:34:57 -0500,2012-01-07 16:32:02 -0500,2012-01-07 14:00:37 -0500,2012-01-07 13:22:10 -0500,2012-01-06 17:51:10 -0500,2012-01-05 21:38:14 -0500,2012-01-05 20:47:39 -0500,2012-01-05 15:48:12 -0500,2012-01-04 22:23:46 -0500,2011-12-27 00:14:42 -0500,2011-12-19 15:09:40 -0500,2011-12-19 10:43:57 -0500,2011-12-15 20:34:51 -0500,2011-12-07 12:27:24 -0500,2011-12-06 19:30:24 -0500,2011-12-06 19:28:55 -0500,2011-12-06 00:25:02 -0500,2011-12-05 22:41:22 -0500,2011-12-02 12:09:20 -0500,2011-12-01 17:38:05 -0500,2011-12-01 17:23:27 -0500,2011-12-01 12:03:03 -0500,2011-11-30 00:46:32 -0500,2011-11-29 23:27:49 -0500,2011-11-29 23:27:00 -0500,2011-11-29 22:04:02 -0500,2011-11-29 16:14:55 -0500,2011-11-29 12:41:53 -0500,2011-11-25 19:26:40 -0500,2011-11-18 16:57:25 -0500,2011-11-18 11:39:16 -0500,2011-11-17 14:03:08 -0500,2011-11-15 19:42:14 -0500,2011-11-15 10:25:33 -0500,2011-11-14 15:01:43 -0500,2011-11-14 14:58:02 -0500,2011-11-11 17:00:57 -0500,2011-11-11 11:53:42 -0500,2011-11-09 00:23:44 -0500,2011-11-08 16:44:13 -0500,2011-11-08 16:04:56 -0500,2011-11-08 15:52:51 -0500,2011-11-08 15:34:00 -0500,2011-11-08 15:17:47 -0500,2011-11-06 17:05:51 -0500,2011-11-02 17:34:12 -0400,2011-11-02 15:51:16 -0400,2011-11-02 15:43:52 -0400,2011-10-29 17:30:45 -0400,2011-10-28 11:53:05 -0400,2011-10-27 14:39:18 -0400,2011-10-27 09:41:25 -0400,2011-10-27 07:57:52 -0400,2011-10-25 18:40:57 -0400,2011-10-25 18:13:56 -0400,2011-10-21 09:58:03 -0400,2011-10-20 23:18:37 -0400,2011-10-18 13:48:37 -0400,2011-10-18 13:39:08 -0400,2011-10-16 16:47:01 -0400,2011-10-14 22:09:44 -0400,2011-10-14 11:19:29 -0400,2011-10-14 09:59:44 -0400,2011-10-14 09:59:43 -0400,2011-10-14 07:38:01 -0400,2011-10-13 19:33:15 -0400,2011-10-13 16:07:06 -0400,2011-10-13 16:01:53 -0400,2011-10-11 14:46:15 -0400,2011-10-07 11:14:26 -0400,2011-10-07 09:57:19 -0400,2011-10-07 09:55:37 -0400,2011-10-07 09:49:49 -0400,2011-10-07 08:32:01 -0400,2011-10-07 08:06:20 -0400,2011-10-07 01:47:19 -0400,2011-10-06 20:59:52 -0400,2011-10-06 17:18:06 -0400,2011-10-06 17:02:57 -0400,2011-10-05 23:41:20 -0400,2011-10-05 23:34:18 -0400,2011-10-05 23:33:34 -0400,2011-10-04 18:01:30 -0400,2011-10-04 14:54:11 -0400,2011-10-04 13:27:48 -0400,2011-10-04 13:26:40 -0400,2011-10-04 13:22:45 -0400,2011-10-04 13:21:20 -0400,2011-10-04 13:09:04 -0400,2011-10-01 02:05:42 -0400,2011-09-30 20:41:54 -0400,2011-09-29 01:42:44 -0400,2011-09-28 17:20:14 -0400,2011-09-25 17:41:25 -0400,2011-09-25 16:25:20 -0400,2011-09-25 16:23:48 -0400,2011-09-25 16:23:17 -0400,2011-09-25 16:22:35 -0400}
```

I think it'll be best to have x-axis as the "days of the week", and the y axis as time. So I `GatherBy` the above here:

```
{{{Wednesday,11:58:38},{Wednesday,20:38:18},{Wednesday,19:39:10},{Wednesday,19:16:42},{Wednesday,18:54:37},{Wednesday,18:00:31},{Wednesday,22:51:27},{Wednesday,22:51:27},{Wednesday,20:43:29},{Wednesday,20:12:00},{Wednesday,20:11:28},{Wednesday,20:11:28},{Wednesday,18:47:40},{Wednesday,17:01:58},{Wednesday,17:01:18},{Wednesday,15:27:57},{Wednesday,13:00:05},{Wednesday,12:54:50},{Wednesday,12:33:31},{Wednesday,11:08:38},{Wednesday,00:29:32},{Wednesday,23:44:54},{Wednesday,19:56:17},{Wednesday,19:55:32},{Wednesday,13:05:58},{Wednesday,22:23:46},{Wednesday,12:27:24},{Wednesday,00:46:32},{Wednesday,00:23:44},{Wednesday,17:34:12},{Wednesday,15:51:16},{Wednesday,15:43:52},{Wednesday,23:41:20},{Wednesday,23:34:18},{Wednesday,23:33:34},{Wednesday,17:20:14}},{{Tuesday,20:18:03},{Tuesday,15:59:18},{Tuesday,15:46:30},{Tuesday,15:44:11},{Tuesday,15:34:23},{Tuesday,13:14:45},{Tuesday,12:09:18},{Tuesday,11:44:13},{Tuesday,20:25:14},{Tuesday,17:36:19},{Tuesday,16:54:37},{Tuesday,14:32:31},{Tuesday,13:53:10},{Tuesday,13:31:14},{Tuesday,12:22:51},{Tuesday,12:21:57},{Tuesday,11:12:31},{Tuesday,20:17:27},{Tuesday,16:23:31},{Tuesday,16:23:31},{Tuesday,12:12:50},{Tuesday,11:19:45},{Tuesday,19:58:55},{Tuesday,19:55:15},{Tuesday,19:02:29},{Tuesday,18:53:18},{Tuesday,00:14:42},{Tuesday,19:30:24},{Tuesday,19:28:55},{Tuesday,00:25:02},{Tuesday,23:27:49},{Tuesday,23:27:00},{Tuesday,22:04:02},{Tuesday,16:14:55},{Tuesday,12:41:53},{Tuesday,19:42:14},{Tuesday,10:25:33},{Tuesday,16:44:13},{Tuesday,16:04:56},{Tuesday,15:52:51},{Tuesday,15:34:00},{Tuesday,15:17:47},{Tuesday,18:40:57},{Tuesday,18:13:56},{Tuesday,13:48:37},{Tuesday,13:39:08},{Tuesday,14:46:15},{Tuesday,18:01:30},{Tuesday,14:54:11},{Tuesday,13:27:48},{Tuesday,13:26:40},{Tuesday,13:22:45},{Tuesday,13:21:20},{Tuesday,13:09:04}},{{Monday,21:30:05},{Monday,17:12:31},{Monday,17:12:11},{Monday,13:03:09},{Monday,17:56:32},{Monday,21:00:46},{Monday,18:52:58},{Monday,17:37:17},{Monday,15:09:40},{Monday,10:43:57},{Monday,22:41:22},{Monday,15:01:43},{Monday,14:58:02}},{{Sunday,23:34:37},{Sunday,23:30:04},{Sunday,23:22:53},{Sunday,12:56:40},{Sunday,20:29:34},{Sunday,10:05:09},{Sunday,13:23:25},{Sunday,20:28:58},{Sunday,16:33:37},{Sunday,17:05:51},{Sunday,16:47:01},{Sunday,17:41:25},{Sunday,16:25:20},{Sunday,16:23:48},{Sunday,16:23:17},{Sunday,16:22:35}},{{Saturday,14:52:10},{Saturday,17:05:16},{Saturday,18:55:28},{Saturday,22:03:11},{Saturday,16:08:24},{Saturday,18:43:48},{Saturday,16:34:57},{Saturday,16:32:02},{Saturday,14:00:37},{Saturday,13:22:10},{Saturday,17:30:45},{Saturday,02:05:42}},{{Friday,20:08:30},{Friday,16:24:57},{Friday,19:34:13},{Friday,15:36:14},{Friday,14:21:04},{Friday,12:25:53},{Friday,00:44:51},{Friday,00:37:29},{Friday,21:34:39},{Friday,10:25:51},{Friday,10:26:19},{Friday,17:51:10},{Friday,12:09:20},{Friday,19:26:40},{Friday,16:57:25},{Friday,11:39:16},{Friday,17:00:57},{Friday,11:53:42},{Friday,11:53:05},{Friday,09:58:03},{Friday,22:09:44},{Friday,11:19:29},{Friday,09:59:44},{Friday,09:59:43},{Friday,07:38:01},{Friday,11:14:26},{Friday,09:57:19},{Friday,09:55:37},{Friday,09:49:49},{Friday,08:32:01},{Friday,08:06:20},{Friday,01:47:19},{Friday,20:41:54}},{{Thursday,16:34:40},{Thursday,12:41:37},{Thursday,12:41:04},{Thursday,11:07:45},{Thursday,11:06:29},{Thursday,09:53:11},{Thursday,09:51:12},{Thursday,07:31:04},{Thursday,16:39:31},{Thursday,16:38:39},{Thursday,13:13:43},{Thursday,11:42:41},{Thursday,08:58:36},{Thursday,07:42:36},{Thursday,21:03:46},{Thursday,21:03:46},{Thursday,13:40:40},{Thursday,21:38:14},{Thursday,20:47:39},{Thursday,15:48:12},{Thursday,20:34:51},{Thursday,17:38:05},{Thursday,17:23:27},{Thursday,12:03:03},{Thursday,14:03:08},{Thursday,14:39:18},{Thursday,09:41:25},{Thursday,07:57:52},{Thursday,23:18:37},{Thursday,19:33:15},{Thursday,16:07:06},{Thursday,16:01:53},{Thursday,20:59:52},{Thursday,17:18:06},{Thursday,17:02:57},{Thursday,01:42:44}}}
```

From here I'm stuck on how to actually display this onto a chart (preferably, `BoxWhiskerChart`)

#### Input Form:

```
{{{"Wednesday", "11:58:38"}, {"Wednesday", "20:38:18"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "19:39:10"}, {"Wednesday", "19:16:42"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "18:54:37"}, {"Wednesday", "18:00:31"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "22:51:27"}, {"Wednesday", "22:51:27"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "20:43:29"}, {"Wednesday", "20:12:00"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "20:11:28"}, {"Wednesday", "20:11:28"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "18:47:40"}, {"Wednesday", "17:01:58"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "17:01:18"}, {"Wednesday", "15:27:57"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "13:00:05"}, {"Wednesday", "12:54:50"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "12:33:31"}, {"Wednesday", "11:08:38"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "00:29:32"}, {"Wednesday", "23:44:54"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "19:56:17"}, {"Wednesday", "19:55:32"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "13:05:58"}, {"Wednesday", "22:23:46"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "12:27:24"}, {"Wednesday", "00:46:32"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "00:23:44"}, {"Wednesday", "17:34:12"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "15:51:16"}, {"Wednesday", "15:43:52"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "23:41:20"}, {"Wednesday", "23:34:18"}, {"Wednesday", 
   "23:33:34"}, {"Wednesday", "17:20:14"}}, {{"Tuesday", 
   "20:18:03"}, {"Tuesday", "15:59:18"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "15:46:30"}, {"Tuesday", "15:44:11"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "15:34:23"}, {"Tuesday", "13:14:45"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "12:09:18"}, {"Tuesday", "11:44:13"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "20:25:14"}, {"Tuesday", "17:36:19"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "16:54:37"}, {"Tuesday", "14:32:31"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "13:53:10"}, {"Tuesday", "13:31:14"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "12:22:51"}, {"Tuesday", "12:21:57"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "11:12:31"}, {"Tuesday", "20:17:27"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "16:23:31"}, {"Tuesday", "16:23:31"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "12:12:50"}, {"Tuesday", "11:19:45"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "19:58:55"}, {"Tuesday", "19:55:15"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "19:02:29"}, {"Tuesday", "18:53:18"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "00:14:42"}, {"Tuesday", "19:30:24"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "19:28:55"}, {"Tuesday", "00:25:02"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "23:27:49"}, {"Tuesday", "23:27:00"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "22:04:02"}, {"Tuesday", "16:14:55"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "12:41:53"}, {"Tuesday", "19:42:14"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "10:25:33"}, {"Tuesday", "16:44:13"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "16:04:56"}, {"Tuesday", "15:52:51"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "15:34:00"}, {"Tuesday", "15:17:47"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "18:40:57"}, {"Tuesday", "18:13:56"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "13:48:37"}, {"Tuesday", "13:39:08"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "14:46:15"}, {"Tuesday", "18:01:30"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "14:54:11"}, {"Tuesday", "13:27:48"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "13:26:40"}, {"Tuesday", "13:22:45"}, {"Tuesday", 
   "13:21:20"}, {"Tuesday", "13:09:04"}}, {{"Monday", 
   "21:30:05"}, {"Monday", "17:12:31"}, {"Monday", 
   "17:12:11"}, {"Monday", "13:03:09"}, {"Monday", 
   "17:56:32"}, {"Monday", "21:00:46"}, {"Monday", 
   "18:52:58"}, {"Monday", "17:37:17"}, {"Monday", 
   "15:09:40"}, {"Monday", "10:43:57"}, {"Monday", 
   "22:41:22"}, {"Monday", "15:01:43"}, {"Monday", 
   "14:58:02"}}, {{"Sunday", "23:34:37"}, {"Sunday", 
   "23:30:04"}, {"Sunday", "23:22:53"}, {"Sunday", 
   "12:56:40"}, {"Sunday", "20:29:34"}, {"Sunday", 
   "10:05:09"}, {"Sunday", "13:23:25"}, {"Sunday", 
   "20:28:58"}, {"Sunday", "16:33:37"}, {"Sunday", 
   "17:05:51"}, {"Sunday", "16:47:01"}, {"Sunday", 
   "17:41:25"}, {"Sunday", "16:25:20"}, {"Sunday", 
   "16:23:48"}, {"Sunday", "16:23:17"}, {"Sunday", 
   "16:22:35"}}, {{"Saturday", "14:52:10"}, {"Saturday", 
   "17:05:16"}, {"Saturday", "18:55:28"}, {"Saturday", 
   "22:03:11"}, {"Saturday", "16:08:24"}, {"Saturday", 
   "18:43:48"}, {"Saturday", "16:34:57"}, {"Saturday", 
   "16:32:02"}, {"Saturday", "14:00:37"}, {"Saturday", 
   "13:22:10"}, {"Saturday", "17:30:45"}, {"Saturday", 
   "02:05:42"}}, {{"Friday", "20:08:30"}, {"Friday", 
   "16:24:57"}, {"Friday", "19:34:13"}, {"Friday", 
   "15:36:14"}, {"Friday", "14:21:04"}, {"Friday", 
   "12:25:53"}, {"Friday", "00:44:51"}, {"Friday", 
   "00:37:29"}, {"Friday", "21:34:39"}, {"Friday", 
   "10:25:51"}, {"Friday", "10:26:19"}, {"Friday", 
   "17:51:10"}, {"Friday", "12:09:20"}, {"Friday", 
   "19:26:40"}, {"Friday", "16:57:25"}, {"Friday", 
   "11:39:16"}, {"Friday", "17:00:57"}, {"Friday", 
   "11:53:42"}, {"Friday", "11:53:05"}, {"Friday", 
   "09:58:03"}, {"Friday", "22:09:44"}, {"Friday", 
   "11:19:29"}, {"Friday", "09:59:44"}, {"Friday", 
   "09:59:43"}, {"Friday", "07:38:01"}, {"Friday", 
   "11:14:26"}, {"Friday", "09:57:19"}, {"Friday", 
   "09:55:37"}, {"Friday", "09:49:49"}, {"Friday", 
   "08:32:01"}, {"Friday", "08:06:20"}, {"Friday", 
   "01:47:19"}, {"Friday", "20:41:54"}}, {{"Thursday", 
   "16:34:40"}, {"Thursday", "12:41:37"}, {"Thursday", 
   "12:41:04"}, {"Thursday", "11:07:45"}, {"Thursday", 
   "11:06:29"}, {"Thursday", "09:53:11"}, {"Thursday", 
   "09:51:12"}, {"Thursday", "07:31:04"}, {"Thursday", 
   "16:39:31"}, {"Thursday", "16:38:39"}, {"Thursday", 
   "13:13:43"}, {"Thursday", "11:42:41"}, {"Thursday", 
   "08:58:36"}, {"Thursday", "07:42:36"}, {"Thursday", 
   "21:03:46"}, {"Thursday", "21:03:46"}, {"Thursday", 
   "13:40:40"}, {"Thursday", "21:38:14"}, {"Thursday", 
   "20:47:39"}, {"Thursday", "15:48:12"}, {"Thursday", 
   "20:34:51"}, {"Thursday", "17:38:05"}, {"Thursday", 
   "17:23:27"}, {"Thursday", "12:03:03"}, {"Thursday", 
   "14:03:08"}, {"Thursday", "14:39:18"}, {"Thursday", 
   "09:41:25"}, {"Thursday", "07:57:52"}, {"Thursday", 
   "23:18:37"}, {"Thursday", "19:33:15"}, {"Thursday", 
   "16:07:06"}, {"Thursday", "16:01:53"}, {"Thursday", 
   "20:59:52"}, {"Thursday", "17:18:06"}, {"Thursday", 
   "17:02:57"}, {"Thursday", "01:42:44"}}}
```

Comment: Can you give that second dataset in `InputForm` so that we don't need to keep it in text format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the days and times in the gathered data list are strings you could do something like

```
days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
   "Saturday", "Sunday"};

data2 = Reap[
    Sow[(AbsoluteTime[#2] - AbsoluteTime["00:00:00"])/3600., #1] & @@@
      Flatten[data, 1],
    days, #2 &][[2, All, 1]];

Show[BoxWhiskerChart[data2],
  FrameTicks -> {Thread[{Range[7], days}],
   {#, IntegerString[#, 10, 2] <> ":00"} & /@ Range[0, 24, 4],
   Thread[{Range[7], ""}], Thread[{Range[0, 24, 4], ""}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is amazing! :D You are a genius!

Comment: Why do the results for Friday not surprise me? ^_^

Comment: Putting together `Reap[Sow @@@ ...]` and Graphics Skillz: very nice. +1 :-)

Comment: Also, congratulations on getting the *first* Enthusiast badge.